# Operation with dates in Grocery CRUD and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

In table Employees I have columns: start_date(dd/mm/yyyy), end_date(dd/mm/yyyy) and period(dd/mm/yyyy). 
I want to put calculation in column period = end_date - start_date.
I don't now haw to take data from columns start_date and end_date and write operation for column period. Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an SQL question IMO. But you tagged it as codeigniter so I guess you need CI code to go with this.

Anyway you can use DATEDIFF on your query. Like so.

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(start_date,end_date) AS DiffDate";
```

Then fire it up on CI using query().

```
$qry = $this->db->query($sql);
return $qry->result();
```